# How to get a values recursively in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have below sample data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempData1') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #tempData1

CREATE TABLE #tempData1
(
     ParentItemId varchar(20),
     ChildItemId varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #tempData1 VALUES('2000-194-819','2000-212-595')
INSERT INTO #tempData1 VALUES('2000-212-771','2000-212-704')
INSERT INTO #tempData1 VALUES('2000-212-704','2000-212-705')
INSERT INTO #tempData1 VALUES('2000-212-595','2000-211-801')
INSERT INTO #tempData1 VALUES('2000-212-801','2000-211-578')
```

I want to find `ParentItemId` and its children

```
WHERE ParentItemId = '2000-194-819'
```

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT B1.ParentItemID 
FROM #tempData1 B1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B2.ParentItemID 
                  FROM #tempData1 B2 
                  WHERE B2.ParentItemID = B2.ChildItemId)
  AND ParentItemID = '2000-194-819'
```

Current output:

```
'2000-194-819'
```

Expected output:

```
2000-194-819
2000-212-595
2000-212-801
```

Please help.

Comment: This is the textbook case for a [recursive cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186243(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with
n as (
  select ParentItemId, ChildItemId 
  from #tempData1 
  where ParentItemID = '2000-194-819'
 union all
  select d.ParentItemId, d.ChildItemId
  from n 
  join #tempData1 d on d.ParentItemId = n.ChildItemId
)
select * from n
```

The recursive CTE is made of two parts:

- The first part of the CTE -- the *anchor member* -- is located before the `UNION ALL` clause and retrieves the first set of rows; it's the starting point:

  ```
   select ParentItemId, ChildItemId 
   from #tempData1 
   where ParentItemID = '2000-194-819'
  ```
- The second part of the CTE -- the *recursive member* -- is placed after the `UNION ALL` clause. This part is executed iteratively for the new rows retrieved until it doesn't return any more rows. This way you can walk a graph, as we are doing here.

  ```
   select d.ParentItemId, d.ChildItemId
   from n 
   join #tempData1 d on d.ParentItemId = n.ChildItemId
  ```